# I can't get all ARecords of the Dns Zone

Tags: c#, dns

I programmed a project to manage Dns. I could code for create and delete Zone, NsRecord and ARecord, but I can't get ARecords of the Zone.
Can anyone guide me?

This is sample of my code:

```
private void CreateZone(string domainName)
{
    wmiScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + System.Environment.MachineName + "\\ROOT\\MicrosoftDNs");
    wmiScope.Connect();
    var zonePath = new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNs_Zone");
    var zone = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, zonePath, null);
    var inParams = zone.GetMethodParameters("CreateZone");

    inParams.Properties["ZoneName"].Value = domainName;
    inParams.Properties["ZoneType"].Value = 0;

    zone.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", inParams, null);

    var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNs_SOAType WHERE OwnerName = '" + domainName + "'");
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiScope, query);
    var zoneRecordes = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject zoneRecorde in zoneRecordes)
    {
        var soaParams = zoneRecorde.GetMethodParameters("Modify");
        soaParams.Properties["PrimaryServer"].Value = "ns1.domain.com";
        soaParams.Properties["ResponsibleParty"].Value = "contact@domain.com";
        zoneRecorde.InvokeMethod("Modify", soaParams, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is more helpful if you show the code to get the Records where you cannot get the ARecord?

Comment: @TimVk i just want a query like this: SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNs_AType WHERE OwnerName LIKE '" + domainname + "' but this query don't support LIKE keyword

Comment: Try the following then: `SELECT * FROM MicrosoftDNs_AType WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), OwnerName) LIKE '" + domainname + "'`

Comment: @TimVK i executed your suggest and returned result "Invalid query"

Comment: Do you get any results if you just execute the query without the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15700/discussion-between-user667429-and-timvk)

Comment: According to the following site (http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=3805&ixReplies=5) you should be able to get the ARecords like this: `ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + dnsServer + "\\root\\microsoftdns");
string strQuery = "select * from microsoftdns_" + recType + 
"type where containername = '" + domain + "' and ownername = '" + strValue + "'";

ManagementObjectSearcher oS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(strQuery);
oS.Scope = oMs;
ManagementObjectCollection oRc = oS.Get();`

Comment: @TIMVK tnx you very much, i must used from 'containername' in WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be complete I'll add the answer that got us to the solution.

According to the following site ([discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/…](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=3805&ixReplies=5)) you should be able to get the ARecords like this:

```
ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + dnsServer + "\\root\\microsoftdns"); 
string strQuery = "select * from microsoftdns_" + recType + "type where containername = '" + domain + "'"; 
ManagementObjectSearcher oS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(strQuery); oS.Scope = oMs; 
ManagementObjectCollection oRc = oS.Get();
```